# My supervisor is suggesting implementing an idea that they previously rejected

Tags: phd, advisor, interpersonal-issues, research-topic

I am in a very confusing situation. I am almost 3 years into my PhD project, and just today my direct supervisor suggested to me to read a paper in the best journal a PhD student would want to publish in.

After going through it, I realised that they have used a method that I spotted during the 5th month of my PhD. I did multiple experiments with that method with success, but at some point my supervisor told me that they didn't want to talk about that analysis anymore. I kept working on it without telling them.

Today, I could not believe that my supervisor was suggesting an idea they have rejected before. I just can't. I double checked the results from back then, and there are multiple significant results. I am not sure if I can keep working with them anymore.

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Exactly what's the problem?  Your super learned something and you're unhappy? Throw me a bone.

Comment: Just to summarize: (1) You did experiments without telling your supervisor. (2) Your supervisor is now suggesting that you do these experiments (which you have already done). (3) Where is the problem? Next meeting with your supervisor, you show them the experiments, and all is well.

Comment: Always consider alternative ideas before you go in hot: Maybe you didn't communicate your ideas effectively enough to your advisor in the first place, or maybe your advisor sees different features in this other research than you suggested originally.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether your supervisor is suggesting implementing the method from the paper they suggest you read, or that they simply asked you to read the paper.

Answer (score 45):

Your supervisor made a mistake. If they had supported you in following this research thread, it would likely have been successful, and you would have been that much further on your research path.

This made you frustrated and disappointed with your advisor, and now you do not want to work with them anymore. I recognize your frustration and very much empathize with it. I had a supervisor shoot down one of my ideas; I got back to it nearly four years later when I was a professor, and it turned out to be highly successful.

However, allow me to offer a few perspectives on your situation.

First, it is extremely difficult to tell what ideas are good, and what ideas aren't. You have the benefit of hindsight now because you saw the journal version and your own experiments (which you hid from your advisor for some reason, more on that in a bit).

Advisors are human beings, and make judgment errors. They are operating with limited time/financial/computational/human resources, and will inevitably make some big mistakes on the way. The main thing that you should do is to *communicate* with them. If you have a lot of faith in an idea: tell your advisor! If you ran experiments despite their advice and they worked out - tell them.

Now, if their reaction is to be mad at you for not listening to them, rather than being happy for being proven wrong, then yes - there is a major issue.

If you were uncomfortable communicating with them which is why you hid your experiments - there's a major issue.

You shouldn't fault your advisor for misjudging a research direction. You should absolutely question how it is handled from now on.

If there are still open problems/directions to take here - you are in an excellent position to explore them I believe. Take the opportunity to learn a lesson in better communication with your advisor (something both of you should clearly do better in), and move forward if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I am kinda in panic mode, because as you guessed we have a major communication issue. First, even if he is young, he never remembers a single thing from what we said, so probably did not even made the link that he suggested a method that his student that was trying to convince him for many months. 

Secondly, he has literally spent 3 hours during the last year and all suggestions in my manuscript do not even make sense, in the next meeting he acknowledges that what he suggested cannot be done.

So, it is a general situation that elevates until I make a change

Comment: @blaha: You need to cultivate relationships to other people in the field that are not your supervisor. Some situations can't be remedied, but you can still get a PhD nevertheless.

Comment: ''I am kinda in panic mode'' I see a lot of posts using language like this on Academia Stack.  I appreciate why you might feel this way, but first thing to do is to calm down so that you can rationally decide on the next best move.  Getting annoyed, angry or panicked will not help.

Comment: Regardless if "he never remembers a single thing from what we said", or not: take notes/minutes; send it to him with a time stamp as email. Not to record every word (as in court), but in line of "with results a), b) c) discussed today, the next experiments to perform address questions 1) ..., 2) ..."  and send it to him. With 3 years into the same (?) project, the detail required to describe the experiments to run might be less, then when you started; but if there is a measurable threshold to pass, include it. This gives *both* of you a record you can revisit, any time.

Answer (score 15):

The universal answer to most questions on this forum applies to your case as well: "Talk to your adviser".

You suggested a method a while ago, he thought it wasn't good, now he's changed his mind. Reasonable people will then have a conversation of the kind "I thought you didn't like this method! What made you change your mind?" Your adviser might have good reasons. Or they respond "I did? I have no recollection of it, but in any case, I must have been confused at the time". The point of it all being that you should have a *conversation*; you might learn something from it, and moreover spending your time trying to read the tea leaves what precisely might be on your adviser's mind is just a waste of everyone's time!

Comment: But OP *did* try without success to show his supervisor the merits of his line of inquiry. *... but at some point my supervisor told me that they didn't want to talk about that analysis anymore...* This reads to me as the supervisor overruling the PhD student. Rather than risk a confrontation and break-up, OP pursued the advised path officially and his own path unofficially. in the circumstances this may have been wise. Now, at Year 3 in the program, OP has to stick it out with the fallible supervisor so he completes soon. The communication problem here has *two* sides to it, don't you think ?

Comment: @Trunk Perhaps. We don't know. But in any case, the solution to a communication problem isn't to just not talk, it's to learn to communicate better!

Answer (score 9):

It happens to lots of people. You'll find it mentioned frequently in PhD memes and comic strips (I remember a phdcomics strip joked about it, but I can't find it now).

If you are planning on remaining in academia and supervising students after your PhD, you'll probably be on the other side of this situation at some point in your career.

It'll happen to you in other non-academic situations as well.

You already have some good results, so you're closer to something publishable than your advisor would have expected if you started these experiments from scratch -- this is a *good* thing! If I were your advisor, I would be quite pleased at being proven wrong.

To avoid the same in the future, you can try to understand what convinced your advisor that this line of inquiry would be productive, and modify the way you sell your preliminary results. Being able to convince others that your preliminary results have merit and that you should receive support on fleshing those out is a skill that you should learn when you're in grad school, because it is a useful skill to have after you graduate.

I see you've mentioned in other comments that your supervisor doesn't remember what you discussed in previous meetings. This is very normal. Remember that they probably have other students to supervise, and classes to teach. These are not trivial responsibilities, and could make it hard to remember every single detail that you discussed with them.

I would often find myself spending a not-insignificant chunk of time recapping what was discussed in previous meetings with my committee members. I found that maintaining a document that summarized every meeting was helpful in jogging their memory and reducing the time spent to remind them about things we'd already discussed.

Answer (score -8):

Go your own way now.

They didn't acknowledge you at first, and now they are furthering their career, with the method you discovered.

The only ethical way to resolve that, is that you become an entrepreneur and escape your university. Your supervisor needs to suffer. Don't let them take credit for your rejected ideas again. You are smart, you can do it.

Comment: The supervisor is not taking credit for OP's work. They may be forgetful, or incompetent - but what happens next is not obvious. The supervisor may admit they were wrong, or downplay the previous dismissal but they may not (or probably - will not) be on OP's paper.